# Remove duplicates while imposing special conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following tibble (only showing the first 10 rows out of ~2 million):

```
   ID              STATUS     NUMBER  FUNCTION LASTMODIFIED         AMOUNT YEAR   MONTH  DAY  
   <chr>           <chr>      <chr>   <chr>    <dttm>               <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 oQYKPAsu9j8AAAF APPROVED   "008"   CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:16:26  2401   2022   3      15   
 2 hhoKPAs_fjUAAAF APPROVED   "101"   CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:15:23  959    2022   3      15   
 3 Ip8KPAsj__4AAAF DENIED     "99"    LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:14:06  0      2022   3      15   
 4 wa4KPAstYwIAAAF DENIED     "99"    LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:13:36  0      2022   3      15   
 5 GucKPAssdaUAAAF APPROVED   "101"   LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:13:21  1084   2022   3      15   
 6 a6AKPAtAsx4AAAF DENIED     "101"   CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:12:02  699    2022   3      15   
 7 a6AKPAtAsx4AAAF DENIED     "101"   CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:12:34  699    2022   3      15   
 8 F4kKPAss7OAAAAF APPROVED   "101"   CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:10:25  3167   2022   3      15   
 9 MK4KPAstiEYAAAF DENIED     "99"    LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:08:46  0      2022   3      15   
10 .nUKPAs.crIAAAF APPROVED    NA     CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:08:35  58     2022   3      15
```

This shows some operations that different users have done on a website, each ID is one unique customer. I want to remove duplicate entries that have taken place within x minutes of each other. So clearly only row 6 or 7 in the data above should be kept (preferably the first). Is there a neat tidyverse/dplyr way of doing this?

My first thought was to ignore the `LASTMODIFIED` column and use `dg &>& filter(!duplicate())` but this will not do what I want.

Comment: *"within x minutes"* and *"ignore `LASTMODIFIED`"* are perfectly incompatible statements

Comment: You're right. I forgot to add that I calculated difference in minutes between two rows (where all other fields are the same) and placed the result in a new column.

Comment: let's say x = 10 minutes.. What shuld happen when 3 events take place 7 minutes after each other. So A = 0, B = 7, C = 14 minutes. Should only B be removed, or B and C?

Comment: @Wimpel - There are no such occurences since maximum two are registered. Alternatively one could restrict the duplicates to happen in the same day. So if there are several duplicates on the same day, only one is kept. To answer your updated question: B AND C should be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is already ordered by `LASTMODIFIED` (at least within each group), then

```r
xseconds <- 600
dat %>%
  group_by(across(-LASTMODIFIED)) %>%
  filter(c(TRUE, as.numeric(diff(LASTMODIFIED), units="secs") > xseconds)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 9
#   ID              STATUS   NUMBER FUNCTION LASTMODIFIED        AMOUNT  YEAR MONTH   DAY
#   <chr>           <chr>     <int> <chr>    <dttm>               <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 oQYKPAsu9j8AAAF APPROVED      8 CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:16:26   2401  2022     3    15
# 2 hhoKPAs_fjUAAAF APPROVED    101 CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:15:23    959  2022     3    15
# 3 Ip8KPAsj__4AAAF DENIED       99 LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:14:06      0  2022     3    15
# 4 wa4KPAstYwIAAAF DENIED       99 LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:13:36      0  2022     3    15
# 5 GucKPAssdaUAAAF APPROVED    101 LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:13:21   1084  2022     3    15
# 6 a6AKPAtAsx4AAAF DENIED      101 CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:12:02    699  2022     3    15
# 7 F4kKPAss7OAAAAF APPROVED    101 CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:10:25   3167  2022     3    15
# 8 MK4KPAstiEYAAAF DENIED       99 LIMIT    2022-03-15 15:08:46      0  2022     3    15
# 9 .nUKPAs.crIAAAF APPROVED     NA CREDIT   2022-03-15 15:08:35     58  2022     3    15
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("oQYKPAsu9j8AAAF", "hhoKPAs_fjUAAAF", "Ip8KPAsj__4AAAF", "wa4KPAstYwIAAAF", "GucKPAssdaUAAAF", "a6AKPAtAsx4AAAF", "a6AKPAtAsx4AAAF", "F4kKPAss7OAAAAF", "MK4KPAstiEYAAAF", ".nUKPAs.crIAAAF"), STATUS = c("APPROVED", "APPROVED", "DENIED", "DENIED", "APPROVED", "DENIED", "DENIED", "APPROVED", "DENIED", "APPROVED"), NUMBER = c(8L, 101L, 99L, 99L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 99L, NA), FUNCTION = c("CREDIT", "CREDIT", "LIMIT", "LIMIT", "LIMIT", "CREDIT", "CREDIT", "CREDIT", "LIMIT", "CREDIT" ), LASTMODIFIED = structure(c(1647371786, 1647371723, 1647371646, 1647371616, 1647371601, 1647371522, 1647371554, 1647371425, 1647371326, 1647371315), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), AMOUNT = c(2401L, 959L, 0L, 0L, 1084L, 699L, 699L, 3167L, 0L, 58L), YEAR = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), MONTH = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), DAY = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: So it only removes duplicates that differs in less than 600 seconds? I tried doing it when i put xseconds = 10 and it still removed line 6.  It should NOT remove it right? Since 15:12:02 - 15:10:25 > 10 second.

Comment: Check again, please ... for some reason, an edit to change the hard-coded 600 to `xseconds` did not stay ...